# Set maximum width using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using

```
$('#myDiv').width('80vw');
```

but want it to also state a max-width of 1200px. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2):

I think we can use jquery `.css` function.

```
$('#myDiv').css('max-width','1200px');
```

Comment: I recommend make a css class for make more clearing.